# Como guardar un archivo PDF descargado como arreglo de bytes que fue obtenido desde API Rest WS

Tags: xamarin.forms

Estoy intentando guardar un archivo PDF, lo obtengo a través de API Rest y llega como un array de bytes.

```
byte[] response = await caller.DownloadFile(url); 
string documentPath = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
string fileName = "downloadfile.pdf";
string path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, response);
```

Arriba mi implementación actual (snippet). Al ejecutar no muestra ningun error pero cuando busco el archivo en la carpeta del proyecto/cache dentro del emulador android no se muestra ningun archivo, la carpeta permanece vacía. Tambien intente cambiar de directorio con `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` y `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` pero ningun archivo se ve creado y ninguna carpeta.

Que me estoy perdiendo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estamos en una comunidad de habla hispana que solo acepta preguntas y respuestas en ese idioma. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y traduce tu respuesta al castellano. Un saludo

Comment: Lo lamento, pensé estar en el sitio en ingles. Podrían habilitar de vuelta mi consulta ya quedó editada al español